# More efficient way of getting count from every month of the year

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

I was wondering if there's a more efficient way of getting a count from every month of the year other then the way I'm currently doing. Currently I'm using a single select statement to get count from say Jan, Mar, so on and then joining them all into a single select statement.

```
Select distinct
    count(item1 + item2) as 'Count of Items',
    month(sub_date) as 'month'

from table1
where month(sub_date)='1'
and year(sub_date)='2012'
```

I would repeat that from month 1-12 and then join the 12 select statement to get a table of something like this

```
jan feb mar apr may jun july aug sept oct nov dec
1   2   2   1   3   5   5    2    6   7   2   1
```

Any information on how to go about redoing my query would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use a `GROUP BY` on both the `month(sub_date)` and `year(sub_date)`:

```
Select 
    count(item1 + item2) as 'Count of Items',
    month(sub_date) as 'month',
    year(sub_date) as year
from table1
group by month(sub_date), year(sub_date)
```

The result for this will be in multiple rows. the `GROUP BY` both the `month` and `year` will allow you to return multiple years, if you want to return only 2012, then you could include your original `WHERE year(sub_date) =2012` clause similar to this:

```
Select 
    count(item1 + item2) as 'Count of Items',
    month(sub_date) as 'month'
from table1
where year(sub_date) = 2012
group by month(sub_date)
```

Then if you want the data in a single row for each year, then you can apply the *pivot* function.

```
select *
from
(
    Select item1 + item2 Items,
        month(sub_date) as 'month'
    from table1
    where year(sub_date) =2012
) src
pivot
(
    sum(Items)
    for month in ([1], [2])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9a67/4). The `PIVOT` function transforms data from rows into columns.

Comment: The OP only wants it for one year, as can be seen in the select list. Also, GROUP BY does not use AND to separate fields.

Comment: @siride I am aware of that, I was showing how this could be implemented using a `GROUP BY` on both the `month` and `year`

Comment: This looks correct, I'll mess around with it to see if it does what I want. Thanks!

Comment: @user2146212 See this demo - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9a67/5 -- I think you might want to use `sum()` as the aggregate function not `count`, but you will know better with your actual data

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` is what you want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

```
SELECT MONTH(sub_date) AS [month],
       COUNT(item1 + item2) AS [Count of Items]
  FROM table1
 WHERE YEAR(sub_date) = 2012
 GROUP BY MONTH(sub_date)
```

This assumes, as I've surmised from your post, that you just want 12 rows, one for each month of a given year (in this case, 2012). If you want to include all years, then you can add that to your `GROUP BY` clause like so:

```
 GROUP BY YEAR(sub_date), MONTH(sub_date)
```

Comment: I want a single column for each month, that's why I'm currently joining the single select statement for each month.